# SecondaryIndexPersister on Azure is throwing exception when saga is started with the same key as historically completed saga

Tags: nservicebus, nservicebus-sagas

We use Sagas with Azure Persistance.

We have a saga which can be compared with a user session handler. The unique key for that session is the mobile number of the user. The first time a text message is received a saga is created for that mobile number. The saga data record and secondary index are created in Azure Table Storage.

After a while the saga is marked as completed. The saga data entry is removed but the secondary index remains in table storage.

Again, a moment later a new message from the same mobile number is received. There is no active saga for that mobile number so a new instance in created (but with the same sagaId as the historical completed saga probably because the secondairy index still exists). The message initiating the saga is not processed bacause of the following exception:

```
NServiceBus.SagaPersisters.Azure.RetryNeededException: This operation requires a retry as it wasn't possible to successfully process it now.
   at NServiceBus.SagaPersisters.Azure.SecondaryIndeces.SecondaryIndexPersister.Insert(IContainSagaData sagaData) in C:\BuildAgent\work\32a824616368e685\src\NServiceBus.Azure\SagaPersisters\Azure\SecondaryIndeces\SecondaryIndexPersister.cs:line 89
   at NServiceBus.SagaPersisters.Azure.AzureSagaPersister.Save(IContainSagaData saga) in C:\BuildAgent\work\32a824616368e685\src\NServiceBus.Azure\SagaPersisters\Azure\AzureSagaPersister.cs:line 47
   at NServiceBus.SagaPersistenceBehavior.Invoke(IncomingContext context, Action next) in C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Sagas\SagaPersistenceBehavior.cs:line 118
   at NServiceBus.BehaviorChain`1.InvokeNext(T context) in C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line 107
   at NServiceBus.BehaviorChain`1.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<InvokeNext>b__0() in C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line 95
   at NServiceBus.SetCurrentMessageBeingHandledBehavior.Invoke(IncomingContext context, Action next) in C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Unicast\Behaviors\SetCurrentMessageBeingHandledBehavior.cs:line 17
   at NServiceBus.BehaviorChain`1.InvokeNext(T context) in C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line 107
   at NServiceBus.BehaviorChain`1.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<InvokeNext>b__0() in C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line 95
   at NServiceBus.LoadHandlersBehavior.Invoke(IncomingContext context, Action next) in C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Unicast\Behaviors\LoadHandlersBehavior.cs:line 45
   at NServiceBus.BehaviorChain`1.InvokeNext(T context) in C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line 107
   at NServiceBus.BehaviorChain`1.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<InvokeNext>b__0() in C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line 95
   at NServiceBus.InvokeSagaNotFoundBehavior.Invoke(IncomingContext context, Action next) in C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Unicast\Behaviors\InvokeSagaNotFoundBehavior.cs:line 17
   at NServiceBus.BehaviorChain`1.InvokeNext(T context) in C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line 107
   at NServiceBus.BehaviorChain`1.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<InvokeNext>b__0() in C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line 95
   at NServiceBus.BehaviorChain`1.InvokeNext(T context) in C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line 107
   at NServiceBus.BehaviorChain`1.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<InvokeNext>b__0() in C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line 95
   at NServiceBus.ExecuteLogicalMessagesBehavior.Invoke(IncomingContext context, Action next) in C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Unicast\Messages\ExecuteLogicalMessagesBehavior.cs:line 24
   at NServiceBus.BehaviorChain`1.InvokeNext(T context) in C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line 107
   at NServiceBus.BehaviorChain`1.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<InvokeNext>b__0() in C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line 95
   at NServiceBus.BehaviorChain`1.InvokeNext(T context) in C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line 107
   at NServiceBus.BehaviorChain`1.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<InvokeNext>b__0() in C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line 95
   at NServiceBus.BehaviorChain`1.InvokeNext(T context) in C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line 107
   at NServiceBus.BehaviorChain`1.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<InvokeNext>b__0() in C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line 95
   at NServiceBus.BehaviorChain`1.InvokeNext(T context) in C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line 107
   at NServiceBus.BehaviorChain`1.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<InvokeNext>b__0() in C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line 95
   at NServiceBus.BehaviorChain`1.InvokeNext(T context) in C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line 107
   at NServiceBus.BehaviorChain`1.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<InvokeNext>b__0() in C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line 95
   at NServiceBus.UnitOfWorkBehavior.Invoke(IncomingContext context, Action next) in C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\UnitOfWork\UnitOfWorkBehavior.cs:line 42
   at NServiceBus.BehaviorChain`1.InvokeNext(T context) in C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line 107
   at NServiceBus.BehaviorChain`1.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<InvokeNext>b__0() in C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line 95
   at NServiceBus.ChildContainerBehavior.Invoke(IncomingContext context, Action next) in C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Unicast\Behaviors\ChildContainerBehavior.cs:line 17
   at NServiceBus.BehaviorChain`1.InvokeNext(T context) in C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line 107
   at NServiceBus.BehaviorChain`1.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<InvokeNext>b__0() in C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line 95
   at NServiceBus.ProcessingStatisticsBehavior.Invoke(IncomingContext context, Action next) in C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Monitoring\ProcessingStatisticsBehavior.cs:line 23
   at NServiceBus.BehaviorChain`1.InvokeNext(T context) in C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line 107
   at NServiceBus.BehaviorChain`1.Invoke() in C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line 52
   at NServiceBus.Pipeline.PipelineExecutor.Execute[T](BehaviorChain`1 pipelineAction, T context) in C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\PipelineExecutor.cs:line 129
   at NServiceBus.Unicast.Transport.TransportReceiver.OnTransportMessageReceived(TransportMessage msg) in C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Unicast\Transport\TransportReceiver.cs:line 413
   at NServiceBus.Unicast.Transport.TransportReceiver.ProcessMessage(TransportMessage message) in C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Unicast\Transport\TransportReceiver.cs:line 344
   at NServiceBus.Unicast.Transport.TransportReceiver.TryProcess(TransportMessage message) in C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Unicast\Transport\TransportReceiver.cs:line 230
   at NServiceBus.Azure.Transports.WindowsAzureServiceBus.AzureServiceBusDequeueStrategy.TryProcessMessage(Object obj) in C:\BuildAgent\work\2f57832e2eee436e\src\Transport\Receiving\AzureServiceBusDequeueStrategy.cs:line 137
```

Off course I can work around this issue by keeping the saga "running" and set an internal flag within the saga data whether the session is active. But, I want to know why the Secondary index is not removed on Saga completion? Is there something I forgot? Is it a bad design to start a new instance of the saga using the same unique key?

Thanks in advance for your answers/comments.

Environment:

- NServiceBus 5.2.4
- NServiceBus.Azure 6.2.4

Comment: Using the same phone number as your key is a little problematic since it's not unique.

Answer (score 3):

This a bug with Azure Storage persistence.
The fix is in progress and can be tracked at [this Github issue.](https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus.Persistence.AzureStorage/issues/74)